# Slide inner div left infinite loop

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, slide

I have spent the last 3 hours trying to play with jquery and get this right with no luck and have google every possible combination of words to see I can find something similar to what i need. I know it will be really simple, my js is terrible

GOAL: inner div needs to slide left with infinite loop. slider (outer div) has width of 1040px with overflow hidden. inner has width of 3198px with a background image. My goal right now is to have the inner div slide left with the same background image (360 photo) infinitely repeating as if it never ends. Below is my html markup

```
<div class="slider">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.slider {
position: relative;
width: 1040px;
height: 311px;
overflow: hidden;
}
.inner {
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
width: 3198px;
height: 311px;
background: url(img/VirtualTour_NormalLighting.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

My ultimate goal: the first image is basically dead (has no lighting or color), the second has a fire lit up and lights on. As the div slides left, sections of the image needs to light up and the then behind it old sections needs to go back to greyscale. Hope that makes sense. Below are the two images:

http://dreamsynk.com/img/VirtualTour_NormalLighting.jpg
http://dreamsynk.com/img/VirtualTour_ExtraLighting.jpg

ANY help would be so helpful! Been struggling

After some googling i found this:

```
// retrieve the element
 element = document.getElementById("ani");

// reset the transition by...
element.addEventListener("click", function(e){
e.preventDefault;

// -> removing the class
element.classList.remove("delay-1");

// -> triggering reflow /* The actual magic */
// without this it wouldn't work. Try uncommenting the line and the transition won't be     retriggered.
element.offsetWidth = element.offsetWidth;

// -> and re-adding the class
element.classList.add("delay-1");
}, false);
```

Does exactly what i want accept it needs to be as the slide ends and not on click. Even with a timeout function or something so like the above activates after 40 seconds?

Comment: Could you post your JS? Also I don't fully understand what you are trying to achieve, could you clarify the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: Hey i updated my question above with some js i found

Comment: http://www.dreamsynk.com/img/slider example of exactly what i want but it needs to reset at the end. Download the files to see it work smoothly with the animation delays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is not perfect, but it's a start. You can do this with CSS alone. Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/24AEu/2/

Here is a Version with Vendor prefixes: http://jsfiddle.net/24AEu/4/

**CSS**

```
@keyframes move-bg {
    from {
        background-position: 0% 0%;
    }
    to {
        background-position: 150% 0%;
    }
}

@keyframes lightup {
    0% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    50% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
    }
}
.slider {
    position: relative;
    width: 1040px;
    height: 311px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    background-image: url(http://dreamsynk.com/img/VirtualTour_NormalLighting.jpg);
    background-position: 0% 0%;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    animation: move-bg 6s infinite;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-play-state: running;
    animation-timing-function:linear;
}
.inner.light {
    background-image: url(http://dreamsynk.com/img/VirtualTour_ExtraLighting.jpg);
    opacity:0;

    background-position: 0% 0%;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    animation:move-bg 6s infinite, lightup 1s infinite;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-play-state: running;
    animation-timing-function:linear;

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner light"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is missing vendor prefixes... I will append them. Works with FF right away

Comment: You are a ninja! how do i +1 you or give you a thumbs up?

Comment: I need 15 rep first :(

Comment: Thanks for accepting :) don't mind about the vote. I already upvoted your answer, so i can not help you there.

Comment: Not sure how good your js is but i updated my above question with js aswell that i found googling. Is there a way to add a timing function as explained above? Here is a working example of what i have so far http://www.dreamsynk.com/img/slider you will need to download the files as the loading will not work with the animation delays.

Comment: sorry, i can not reply to you here any more. This is becoming to much like a chat. You can not destroy these files. You can make own Copies by clicking **Update**. Changes will be hold in your session. Resart your browser and klick the links in my answer again and everything is reverted. Good luck.